l2TP/IPSec VPN not working on Windows 11 even after troubleshooting
I've recently encountered issues trying to set up a personal l2TP/IPsec w/ PSK VPN on my Windows 11 laptop. I always get "Error 809 - The network connection between your computer and your VPN server could not be established..." I have tested it on other devices (A iPad, a Win 10 laptop and another Win 11 one) and they worked fine. I have spent numerous hours trying to troubleshoot to no avail. What I tried so far (without success):

Trying to set up the VPN using the built-in client multiple times, checking the password, username, address and pre-shared key
Use multiple different hot spots through Wi-Fi and Bluetooth PAP
Disable Windows Defender firewall
Enable MS-CHAP v2 (which was disabled by default for some reason, and applying it was wierd) and CHAP
Make sure that LPC was enabled
Make sure IpSec was not forbidden (registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\RasMan\Parameters ProhibitIpSec DWORD 0
Make sure HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PolicyAgent registry entry "AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule" was DWORD 2
Change DNS from auto to 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1 and also back to auto
Restart Ike and IPSec services
Disable IPv6 on both my Wi-Fi card and WAN miniports
Uninstall all WAN miniports
Reinstall Wi-Fi drivers
System restore

Some other important stuff

My laptop is running Windows 11 Pro Ver 23H2 build 22631.4037. AMD CPU + Nvidia GPU w/ MediaTek MT7921 Wi-Fi 6 chip
The home network is NOT managed by me, but instead my father. He uses a UniFi USG router, although I don't know how he set it up. He also gave it a go on my laptop but couldn't fix it.
We use DDNS instead of a fixed IP address

At this point the only thing left to my knowledge would be to reinstall my entire OS, but currently I don't have the time to save my data, collect the list of all apps I use and etc. However, if I can't resolve this I guess I have no other choice left.
If you have any tips or advice it would be greatly appreciated. I can look up logs and paste them here if needed.
Thanks!

I have also tried disabling Credential Guard, as I've heard it can interfere with MS-CHAPv2. Did not solve the issue.

I eventually managed to resolve the problem without completely resintalling or reseting the pc. I did the following (see if this helps you):

You can "reinstall" Windows using the Fix problems with your PC by using Windows Update option here. I have a suspicion that the issue might have been caused by a broken Windows Update and that this fixed, or maybe some default setting was changed that was reset by this option.
Removed my WiFi card and WAN miniports in device manager with uninstalling the drivers
After this I finally got back Error code 789, so I made sure all my VPN settings were correct (MS-CHAP v2 enabled, PSK, address, and login info). I also made the registry edit needed for NAT-T devices.AssumeUDPEncapsulationContextOnSendRule
After these I now got Error Code 720 (so authentication finally worked). A final removal of the WAN minports and a restart later and now my VPN finally works.

I still don't know what exactly caused the issue, but at least this way I didn't have to do a complete reinstall. Fair warning, the Windows Update fix can take a long time! For me the download and install was around 1-2 hours while using the PC and the restart took around 15 minutes.
